# Uploadify not firing the onProgress event

Tags: javascript, file-upload, uploadify

I'm using Uploadify on my website and trying to integrate my own, more advanced progress bar. I need to get the status of each file upload regularly so I was planning to use the `onProgress` event of Uploadify. If I do this:

```
$('#file-upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/assets/flash/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/upload.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/assets/images/cancel.png',
    'auto'      : false,
    'multi'     : true,
    'queueID'   : 'file-queue',
    'queueSizeLimit':5,
    'sizeLimit' : 104857600,
    'onSelect'  : function(event, ID, fileObj) {
        files.push({id:ID, size:fileObj.size});
        addFileToQueue(ID, fileObj);
        return false;
    },
    'onError'   : function(event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
        alert("Error: Type: " + errorObj.type + " Message: " + errorObj.info);
    },
    'onProgress': function(event, ID, fileObj, data) {
        console.log("progress");
        updateProgress(data);
    }
});
```

Problem is, I never get `progress` logged into console, nor does any code in the `updateProgress` function ever execute. The file uploading does actually work, as I can see the files being uploaded into the uploads directory. I also don't get any errors in the Javascript console.

What could be wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
'onProgress': function(event, ID, fileObj, data) {
    console.log("progress");
    updateProgress(data);
    return false;
}
```

From the docs:

> "The onProgress option allows you to fire a function each time to progress of a file upload changes.  The default function updates the length of the progress bar and percentage displayed.  If the custom function returns false, the default function will not run."

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. It has also come to my attention that no other events will fire like `onComplete` or `onError`, it only seems to be `onSelect` that works :/

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Are you getting any errors in your console? There may be an error that is causing part of the code to fail but not affecting onSelect. Generally if a part of the script fails, it will make everything after it. I would double check your syntax in onError.